# Bug not created on broken build TFS 2010

Tags: build, tfs, tfsbuild

Our CI build definition has stopped creating a bug on build failure.  There are no outstanding build failure bugs.  Any advice on where to look to determine why it would have stopped creating them as we've checked through the build definition and event log on the server to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me when the Process Template has been upgraded out from under me. I have one project now where the build settings do not allow a bug to be creaeted because there is no valid automatic setting for some of the fields. The build template needs to be changed to set the initial fields to valid values.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the Create Work Item on Failure setting in the Build Definition?

[image: Create Work Item on Failure Screenshot]

Comment: We have and it's set to True.